# Drawables used for menus deleted in release build

Tags: android, gradle, build, release, drawable

I am trying to figure out how to make a release build. I followed guides from dev, but unable to keep drawables in my projects that are used for menus

Even when checking shrinkResources as false in build gradle, it still deletes these resources
Hope for some solution

**Also**

I tried modifying gradle like this

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
    }
}
```

And added xml file as advised in res/raw

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:keep="@drawable/ic_delete" />
```

But nothing seems to help

Comment: Where are you storing your drawables? Could you please take a screenshot of the res/drawable directory?

Comment: I just strore them in res/drawable